# Sum of all values in one column considering two others

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I want to find the (Value Column) but it should consider the date (Column A) and the name of the person (Column B) who submitted the data.

[DATA Sheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKqpx.png)

[image]

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you please explain more. Please put your expected result manually. We will try to do it by formula.

Comment: For example I want to be able to find the sum of all values that Joseph submitted on 11/2/2015 which is = 10

Comment: I Think this should do the trick, Thanks pnuts

Comment: =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"Joseph",A:A,"11/2/2015")

Answer (score 1):

Please try [SUMIFS](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumifs.php), for example:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"Joseph",A:A,"11/2/2015")
```

[image: SO33480055 example]